# In tree check if given node is ancestor of another

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I have a problem - I need to answer question if given 2 nodes (A, B) is A ancestor of B. I know that the possible solution is to get the time when I enter the node and the time when I leave it. Based on this I can calculate relationship fast. How to get those 'timestamps' using DFS which can not be implemented using recurrence?

I am not expert in algorithms and C++, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get it. If Your tree in adjacency list then You can go with preprocessing. To each node You need to assign the value when You enter it and when You leave it during DFS, then in constant time You can check it:

```
if (timeIn[b] >= timeIn[a] && timeIn[b] <= timeOut[a]) {
   printf("YES\n");
}
else {
   printf("NO\n");
}
```

where a is possible ancestor of b.

DFS:

```
// INITIALIZE VARs
int time = 0;
stack<int> stackOfChildNodes;
// put root of tree
stackOfChildNodes.push(first);
// go with DFS
while (!stackOfChildNodes.empty()) {
    int current = stackOfChildNodes.top();
    stackOfChildNodes.pop();
    // if node was not visited (time is not set)
    if (timeIn[current] == -1) {
        timeIn[current] = time; // node visited
        time++; // increase time to go further
        stackOfChildNodes.push(current); // include node in processing to leave it in future
        int child = children[current];
        // add descendants to process them
        while (child != 0) {
            stackOfChildNodes.push(child);
            child = descendants[child];
        }
    }
    // if node was visited, so we gonna leave him now
    if (timeIn[current] != -1) {
        timeOut[current] = time-1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With standard augmented thread indices (ATI -- see reference provided below), that provide for node length data structures, usually arrays, answering the question of whether `A` is `B`'s ancestor is not possible in constant time.

If you store the `pred`, `thread` and `depth` (that constitute the fundamental data structures in the ATI scheme) of each node, the question of whether `A` is `B`'s ancestor can be done in `O(N)` time -- just retrace from `B` using the `pred` data structure until you reach the `root` and check if you encounter `A`.

However, you can do the above for each node as a preprocessing step and then have a new node length array, `ancestor` for each node which indicates whether another node is its ancestor or not.

Reference: [Bazaara, Jarvis and Sherali](https://pws.yazd.ac.ir/hasheminezhad/Bazaraa-LP[430912].pdf) page 482.